# Query time indefinitely for too many relationship query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In my database, I have User, Location, Room, and Device. User and Location has many-to-many relationship with UserLocation table, Location and Room is 1-to-many. Room and Device is many-to-many with RoomDevice. So from a single User id, I want to display a list of Device that related to that User. My logic is from an User ID, I will get a list of Location belong to that User. And then from each Location in that list, I will get a list of Room, from each Room in that Room list, I will get a list of Devices. After each time getting a new list of Devices, I will add it to a list of variale then print that total Devices list out. Right now, my code just keep running indefinitely.

```
       var locationList = db.Locations.Where(a => a.UserLocations.Any(b => b.userId == accountID)).ToList();
        int locationCount = locationList.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < locationCount; i++)
        {
            var currentLocation = locationList.ElementAt(i);
            var roomList = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.locationId == currentLocation.locationId).ToList();
            var roomCount = roomList.Count();
            for (int y = 0; y < roomCount; i++)
            {
                var currentRoom = roomList.ElementAt(y);
                var devicee = db.Devices.Where(a => a.RoomDevices.Any(b => b.roomId == currentRoom.roomId)).ToList();
                deviceTotal.AddRange(devicee);
            }
        }
        return Ok(deviceTotal);
```

Comment: for (int y = 0; y < roomCount; i++) should be for (int y = 0; y < roomCount; y++)

You're increasing i and y is always zero which means it can never leave the loop

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't notice that.